# increase IntelliJ java heap size

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3, javac

after a lot of research I could not get a result. I'm new to IntelliJ IDEA, I use 11.1.2 version. I work with 3 modules (3 eclipse projects) and in each of them I setted **Preferences -> Compiler -> Java Compiler** with the following values:

**Maximum heap size (MB):** 512

**Additional command line parameters:**

-target
1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-Xms256m
-Xmx512m
-XX:PermSize=512m

**And also configured Maven runner's VM Options as the following:**

-XX:PermSize=1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Duser.language=en

with skip tests checked...

I also changed **Applications -> IntelliJ IDEA 12 -> Contents -> Info.plist**:

```xml
      <key>VMOptions</key>
      <string>-ea -Xverify:none -Xbootclasspath/a:../lib/boot.jar</string>

      <key>VMOptions.i386</key>
      <string>-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m</string>

      <key>VMOptions.x86_64</key>
      <string>-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m -XX:+UseCompressedOops</string>

      <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
```

But after doing these changes IntelliJ shows me 200-250 MB of heap space allocated on the bottom right... What is wrong?

Comment: The bottom right corner numbers show heap space allocated for IntelliJ Idea itself. You're configuring heap space for java compiler and maven runner. Are you trying to allocate more space for Idea itself?

Comment: Mm?! actually I'm trying to run a project but it explodes with java heap space exception.. any suggestion?

Comment: Bottom right corner is of no interest for you then. When exactly do you get OOM error? Also, is it a maven project?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Adding `-Xms512m -Xmx1024m` settings to Maven runner configurations (not the one in Preferences but the one I created for my project) solved java heap space error for me.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding **MAVEN_OPTS as -Xms512 -Xmx1024m to windows environment variables**. Right click my computer-> advanced-> environment variables and try running the maven build and see if it works.

Comment: I have solved my problem and posted an answer above.. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

The real answer to the question's headline on Mac is here: [How to increase IDE memory limit in IntelliJ IDEA on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578062/how-to-increase-ide-memory-limit-in-intellij-idea-on-mac)

Quoting CrazyCoder:

Now it can take VM options from  `~/Library/Preferences/<appFolder>/idea.vmoptions` and system properties from `~/Library/Preferences/<appFolder>/idea.properties`.