# How to rename a file in IntelliJ without finding usages?

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring

I am developing a Node.js project in IntelliJ.

The only way to rename files seems to be `Shift+F6` which attempts to find all usages which takes too long (~30s - 1min).

Is there a way to simply rename the file without searching for usages?

This only happens when code is stored in Modules (which is necessary to be able to compact empty middle packages).

Comment: found nice plugin check my answer

Comment: Coming from VSCode I was used to just pressing Enter on a file to rename it. I was trying PHPStorm and needed to rename a few files...I was wondering where the rename option was...turns out It was under the context menu item Refactor->Rename

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

IntelliJ must find the usages to rename them, otherwise you're just renaming the file, not refactoring. If you only want to rename the file, use the mv command from a terminal. You can also tell IntelliJ not to look in strings and text, which speeds things up somewhat, but is probably a bad idea in a javascript project (where almost everything is string or text).

I use rename a lot, and on my codebase, which is pretty big, it only takes a couple of seconds. Maybe intellij needs more memory to operate in, so you could try increasing that.

Comment: Good idea about looking into the the memory usage. I generally have two or three IDEs open at once. It's annoying having to jump into Finder to rename. I might log a feature request.

Comment: So default memory is ~700MB. I have changed it to 2048MB thanks to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578062/how-to-increase-ide-memory-limit-in-intellij-idea-on-mac

Answer (score 25):

Best way I have found is to map `ALT+SHIFT+F6` to `Reveal in Finder`. Then just press `enter` and type in new name.

It's good because its very similar to `SHIFT+F6` rename refactor.

Comment: That's the best answer. IntelliJ should assume that the developer knows what he or she is doing when renaming a file. For example, we can easily delete a file. Why not renaming? Also, the question is clear about the developer's goal.

Answer (score 1):

If You are doing it many times, You can create a custom scope for the refactoring:

[image]

There You can narrow the scope to few files/folders/modules etc. And for very narrow scope it will work as normal rename.

Comment: This is a really nice way of limiting the refactor. `Current File` scope works if you simply want to rename the current file.