# IntelliJ Unit Test issues

Tags: intellij-idea, java-7, powermock

I have the following error while attempting to run a Unit Test in IntelliJ. From googling around it seemed like it had to do with using JDK7 and Powermock being incompatible. The suggestion that frequently came up was to add the -XX:-UseSplitVerifier flag. I've tried this by following these instructions: ([How to increase IDE memory limit in IntelliJ IDEA on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578062/how-to-increase-ide-memory-limit-in-intellij-idea-on-mac)) but continue to get the error.

Has anyone else had this issue and resolved it?

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Inconsistent stackmap frames at branch target 48 Exception Details:   Location:
    com/marketplace/impl/MarketplaceLibTestBase.<init>(Lorg/powermock/core/IndicateReloadClass;)V @48: aload_2   Reason:
    Type uninitializedThis (current frame, locals[2]) is not assignable to 'com/marketplace/impl/MarketplaceLibTestBase' (stack map, locals[2])   Current Frame:
    bci: @34
    flags: { flagThisUninit }
    locals: { uninitializedThis, 'org/powermock/core/IndicateReloadClass', uninitializedThis, 'org/powermock/core/IndicateReloadClass', top, 'java/lang/Object' }
    stack: { 'java/lang/Object', 'java/lang/Object' }   Stackmap Frame:
    bci: @48
    flags: { flagThisUninit }
    locals: { uninitializedThis, 'org/powermock/core/IndicateReloadClass', 'com/marketplace/impl/MarketplaceLibTestBase', 'org/powermock/core/IndicateReloadClass' }
    stack: { }   Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a2b 4e4d 1312 9bb8 129d 04bd 0011 5903
    0000010: 2d53 1312 9eb8 12a0 b812 a23a 0519 05b2
    0000020: 12a4 a500 0e2a 01c0 0022 b712 a6a7 000a
    0000030: 2c2d b712 a801 57b1                       Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@48,Object[#45],Object[#34])
    chop_frame(@55,2)

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)   at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)   at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2651)     at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1467)  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.getTestMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:108)    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:84)     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:42)     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:154)     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:49)  at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:231)  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:69)  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:36)    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:27)     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)  at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)   at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)  at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)  at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)     at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:44)   at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)   at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: Facing the same issue but not on IntelliJ but on STS. Noob where you able to find out a solution to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [an old issue on Google Code](https://web.archive.org/web/20160801053548/https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=355):

Try adding

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
   <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
   <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.xml.

Comment: Thanks alot. Trying a bunch of different solutions, this finally resolved my problem.

Comment: Awesome.  Was fighting forever to find out why adding the -XX:-UseSplitVerifier was not working.  Updating to a later version of Javassist did the trick for me too.

Comment: @Joost Papendorp the link is broken

Comment: @JeanValjean Updated it.