# Getting a OutOfMemory error when attempting to update my Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to update IntelliJ IDEA from build 141.177 to 141.178.
When the updated downloads all the files needed, and starts the update, I get this error:

```
Temp. directory: /tmp

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at ie.wombat.jbdiff.JBPatch.bspatch(JBPatch.java:91)
    at com.intellij.updater.BaseUpdateAction.applyDiff(BaseUpdateAction.java:112)
    at com.intellij.updater.UpdateAction.doApply(UpdateAction.java:44)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchAction.apply(PatchAction.java:184)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch$3.forEach(Patch.java:308)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.forEach(Patch.java:360)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.apply(Patch.java:303)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.apply(PatchFileCreator.java:84)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.apply(PatchFileCreator.java:75)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.doInstall(Runner.java:295)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.access$000(Runner.java:18)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner$2.execute(Runner.java:261)
    at com.intellij.updater.SwingUpdaterUI$5.run(SwingUpdaterUI.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The `/tmp` folder should be on my root partition which has 20GiB of size,  and currently it still has about 8GiB left. So I don't really understand what the problem could be here right now. Plus I am not sure about the RAM part, my system is using 40% of my RAM when I do the update.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139036

Comment: Seems to be that everyone got it working randomly when trying again... Does not work for me.

Comment: This is a memory error, not a disk space error. There are usually some ways to increase size for the jvm but I am not sure how this works with the updater. Long shot, maybe - What are your JAVA_OPTS set to, if anything?

Comment: No idea about them, probably not set to anything.

Comment: Try the other update way (downloading the full package)

Comment: That will work of course, tried it allready. Was just hoping that maybe the updater would handle it too. It used to but it seems now something is wrong.

Comment: Then provide a heap dump to JetBrains, so they can fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read the JetBrains [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/increasing-memory-heap.html) & [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13581526/711807) about how to increase the maximum heap size for IntelliJ.

Set `-Xmx2048m` in `idea.vmoptions` (32-bit edition) or `idea64.vmoptions` (64-bit edition), and copy it to the appropriate location, according to the documentation I referred to above.

I would also do `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate and Restart`, just to be sure that the changes took (probably not necessary, but just in case).

I received the exact same stack trace today while attempting to upgrade from 14.1.1 to 14.1.2 via the automatic updater. On OS X, I solved it by renaming `~/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC14/idea.vmoptions` to `idea64.vmoptions`. I already had `-Xmx2048m` set in that file, but apparently it wasn't being read until I renamed it correctly.

Also see YouTrack issue [IDEA-139036](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139036) (thanks to @Meo).

Answer (score 14):

I hit this same problem.  The issue is that idea.vmoptions change the memory for the main intellij process but not the update process.  In my case the update process only had 500m allocated to it.

I got past the problem by leaving the update window open after it got the error.  I then ran `ps -Af | grep java` (I'm running linux).  This showed me the command line for the update process.  I copied it out and changed `-Xmx500m` to `-Xmx1024m`.  I then ran the modified command line in another console, once it was done I exited the original update window and all was good.

Comment: This worked great for me too (using Linux as well). The key is to leave the error window open and then run the modified command. Thanks!