# How can I increase heap size for Idea community edition 14.1.2 on OSX?

Tags: macos, size, heap-memory, limit, intellij-14

I'm running IDEA (community edition) 14.1.2 on my MacBook Air, OSX 10.10.3. The IDEA java process always starts up with -Xmx512m, which is a little small when I have 4G memory. I have been trying to find an answer but looks like what works for most people doesn't for me. I copied /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions over to ~/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC14, and changed -Xmx512m to -Xmx1024m, but nothing changed after I restart.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the 64-bit edition of IDEA (I assume you are, as [all MacBook Air's are 64-bit capable](https://superuser.com/a/268144/79838)), then you need to rename the file `idea64.vmoptions` after copying it to `~/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC14`, or it will be ignored on OS X 10.10.3 Yosemite. Unfortunately, this is not explained in the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/increasing-memory-heap.html).

I would also do `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate and Restart`, just to be sure that the changes took (probably not necessary, but just in case).

Also see [How to increase IDE memory limit in IntelliJ IDEA on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578062/how-to-increase-ide-memory-limit-in-intellij-idea-on-mac/13581526) for other possible solutions (somewhat outdated as it's for IDEA 12, but still relevant.)

Comment: I just realized the java process with -Xmx512m I mentioned was a RemoteMavenServer started by Idea, not the idea itself, and it's not always running. Idea doesn't list its  process as a java process, so I cannot really know how much heap size has been allocated for it. But after I rename idea.vmoptions to idea64.vmoptions, it does seem faster - when I right-click mouse on something, it used to take long time for the popup menu to appear, now it's more prompt.