# distriqt pushnotifications isSupported return false ( version = 3 )

Tags: air, ane, distriqt

I get at Android device (Len. P70, Android.v 5.1)  isSupported false. 
Manifest xml should be ok. 
iOS device works fine.
Latest pushnotifications ANE downloaded (###### 2016.03.28 Updated)

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is a configuration issue. The `isSupported` flag checks the configuration of your application and will return true when you have the required additions.

Make sure you have added the additional ANEs and that you have the latest version of these:

- Core
- GooglePlayServices
- AndroidSupport

Also that you have updated the manifest to include all the new additions (these are different from v2), replacing `APPLICATION_PACKAGE` with your applications package eg `air.com.distriqt.test`:

```
<manifest android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <!-- GCM PERMISSIONS -->                
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Only this application can receive the messages and registration result --> 
    <permission android:name="APPLICATION_PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="APPLICATION_PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="APPLICATION_PACKAGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name="com.distriqt.extension.pushnotifications.gcm.GcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.distriqt.extension.pushnotifications.gcm.InstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.distriqt.extension.pushnotifications.gcm.RegistrationIntentService" android:exported="false" />

        <activity android:name="com.distriqt.extension.pushnotifications.PushNotificationsActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="APPLICATION_PACKAGE.NOTIFICATION_DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>             

        <!-- NOTIFICATIONS -->
        <receiver android:name="com.distriqt.extension.pushnotifications.notifications.receivers.NotificationReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="APPLICATION_PACKAGE.NOTIFICATION_SELECTED" />
                <action android:name="APPLICATION_PACKAGE.NOTIFICATION_DELETED" />
                <action android:name="APPLICATION_PACKAGE.NOTIFICATION_ACTION" />
                <data android:scheme="dtpn" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Check the getting started guide for detailed information: http://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.PushNotifications#get-started

Comment: Core ( 2016.04.01 )
GooglePlayServices ( Updated to v8487000 )
AndroidSupport ( 2015.11.18 )
GooglePlayServices ( 2016.03.28 )
AIR 21 but also try with 19
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="8487000" /> (same number as in GooglePlayServices)
APPLICATION_PACKAGE - according my app id

**Rest of the manifest remain same**

IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1

BUT while compil.
`UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at com.android.dx.ssa.Dominators.<init>(Dominators.java:74)
 at com.android.dx.ssa.Dominators.make(Dominators.java:88) ...`

Comment: Once I do not include <extensionID>com.distriqt.AndroidSupport</extensionID> or <extensionID>com.distriqt.GooglePlayServices</extensionID> compilation is ok. Sure at this case issupport fail

Comment: You should try to increase the memory available to intellij: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578062/how-to-increase-ide-memory-limit-in-intellij-idea-on-mac