# IntelliJ won't start : ERROR - psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I was working with IntelliJ when it's started bugging and finally crashed. I try to reopen it but it's doesn't work. I inspected my log files and I found this error:

```
    2016-04-22 17:50:52,344 [87152908]  ERROR psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider - IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1  Build #IC-145.597.3 
2016-04-22 17:50:52,344 [87152908]  ERROR - psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider - JDK: 1.8.0_60 
2016-04-22 17:50:52,344 [87152908]  ERROR - psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 
2016-04-22 17:50:52,344 [87152908]  ERROR - psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2016-04-22 17:50:52,344 [87152908]  ERROR - psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider - OS: Windows 10 
2016-04-22 17:50:52,345 [87152909]  ERROR - psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider - Last Action: Rerun 
2016-04-22 17:50:52,345 [87152909]  ERROR - psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider - null 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.ZipHandler$1.createAccessor(ZipHandler.java:52)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.ZipHandler$1.createAccessor(ZipHandler.java:44)
    at com.intellij.util.io.FileAccessorCache$1.createValue(FileAccessorCache.java:35)
    at com.intellij.util.io.FileAccessorCache$1.createValue(FileAccessorCache.java:30)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.SLRUCache.get(SLRUCache.java:46)
    at com.intellij.util.io.FileAccessorCache.get(FileAccessorCache.java:62)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.ZipHandler.getZipFileHandle(ZipHandler.java:105)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.ZipHandler.contentsToByteArray(ZipHandler.java:205)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.ArchiveFileSystem.contentsToByteArray(ArchiveFileSystem.java:207)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.contentsToByteArray(PersistentFSImpl.java:509)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualFileImpl.contentsToByteArray(VirtualFileImpl.java:127)
    at com.intellij.psi.ClassFileViewProvider.createFile(ClassFileViewProvider.java:62)
    at com.intellij.psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider.createFile(SingleRootFileViewProvider.java:322)
    at com.intellij.psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider.getPsiInner(SingleRootFileViewProvider.java:167)
    at com.intellij.psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider.getPsi(SingleRootFileViewProvider.java:151)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.file.impl.FileManagerImpl.findFile(FileManagerImpl.java:401)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiManagerImpl.findFile(PsiManagerImpl.java:184)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.file.PsiDirectoryImpl.processChildren(PsiDirectoryImpl.java:197)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.ProjectViewDirectoryHelper.directoryChildrenInProject(ProjectViewDirectoryHelper.java:204)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.ProjectViewDirectoryHelper.getDirectoryChildren(ProjectViewDirectoryHelper.java:154)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.PsiDirectoryNode.getChildrenImpl(PsiDirectoryNode.java:143)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.AbstractPsiBasedNode.getChildren(AbstractPsiBasedNode.java:89)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeStructureBase.getChildElements(AbstractTreeStructureBase.java:47)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.BaseProjectTreeBuilder.expandPathTo(BaseProjectTreeBuilder.java:338)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.BaseProjectTreeBuilder.expandChild(BaseProjectTreeBuilder.java:374)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.BaseProjectTreeBuilder.access$200(BaseProjectTreeBuilder.java:53)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.BaseProjectTreeBuilder$11.run(BaseProjectTreeBuilder.java:393)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ExecutionCallback.setExecuted(ExecutionCallback.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ActionCallback.setRejected(ActionCallback.java:91)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.BaseProjectTreeBuilder.expandChild(BaseProjectTreeBuilder.java:413)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.BaseProjectTreeBuilder.access$200(BaseProjectTreeBuilder.java:53)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.BaseProjectTreeBuilder$11.run(BaseProjectTreeBuilder.java:393)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ExecutionCallback.setExecuted(ExecutionCallback.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ActionCallback.setRejected(ActionCallback.java:91)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.BaseProjectTreeBuilder.expandChild(BaseProjectTreeBuilder.java:413)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.BaseProjectTreeBuilder.access$200(BaseProjectTreeBuilder.java:53)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.BaseProjectTreeBuilder$9.run(BaseProjectTreeBuilder.java:348)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeBuilder$1.process(AbstractTreeBuilder.java:53)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeBuilder$1.process(AbstractTreeBuilder.java:50)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.TransferToEDTQueue.processNext(TransferToEDTQueue.java:99)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.TransferToEDTQueue.access$300(TransferToEDTQueue.java:37)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.TransferToEDTQueue$1.run(TransferToEDTQueue.java:58)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:857)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:658)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:386)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:792)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:465)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1661)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1610)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.DefaultIdeaErrorLogger$1.run(DefaultIdeaErrorLogger.java:86)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:857)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:658)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:386)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Does anybody can help me ? I tried to uninstall and reinstall, to update Java but it didn't work. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running out of memory, and hence you might possibly need to tweak the VM options for your IDE.

Source/Solution: [How to increase IDE memory limit in IntelliJ IDEA on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578062/how-to-increase-ide-memory-limit-in-intellij-idea-on-mac)

Note that for windows, the path for the concerned file is along the lines of "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1\bin\idea64.exe.vmoptions".