# Intellij not respecting vm settings upon startup

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

On El Capitan (osx) here with the following in `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2016.2/idea.vmptions` :

```
-Xms1280m
-Xmx2000m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-Dide.mac.file.chooser.native=false
```

However upon restarting Intellij we see the following setting: `-Xmx768m` . So IJ is ignoring the `idea.vmptions` file .. ?  What is the proper procedure to update those VM settings?

**Update**  I also tried changing the values in

```
sudo vi /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions
```

That also had no effect: still the same -Xmx768m shows up under `ps -ef | grep ntellij`

**Update**  The answer from @morfic inroduced a capability from Intelli to use `Help | Edit custom VM options`.  However the values shown there are identical to the ones above (e.g. -Xmx2000m)  and not respected.

Comment: Do you have any [IDEA_VM_OPTIONS environment variable defined](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/increasing-memory-heap.html)? As per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578062/how-to-increase-ide-memory-limit-in-intellij-idea-on-mac/13581526#13581526) can also try using `Help` -> `Edit Custom VM Options` starting with IJ 15.0.4

Comment: @Morfic  Please make this an answer and I can mark as 'helpful"

Comment: I'm glad if I somehow helped, but if you found the answer yourself starting from a suggestion, I believe it would be better for everyone if you posted it and chose it as the correct one to keep things clearer, don't you agree? :-)

Comment: Btw `However upon restarting Intellij we see the following setting: -Xmx768m` where are you seeing this? Are you sure it's the IJ VM and not something related, such as maven or other subprocess?

Comment: @Morfic  It is fair practice to award "helpful" to an answer that helps lead to a solution.

Comment: I know and I agree, but so far I consider it to be just a simple comment since we did not get to the bottom of the problem yet. Also, did you see my second comment above regarding `However upon restarting Intellij we see the following setting: -Xmx768m`?