# IntelliJ Idea 2016 memory problems on OSX

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, heap-memory

I just updated to Idea 2016.3.2. And keep getting this error.

> There is not enough memory to perform the requested operation. Please
>   increase 'Xmx' setting and restart the IDE for change to take effect.

[image]

The last thing i did was to increase the Xmx memory option to 2048 in the idea.vmoptions file (as instructed by this answer [How to increase IDE memory limit in IntelliJ IDEA on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578062/how-to-increase-ide-memory-limit-in-intellij-idea-on-mac/13581526#13581526))

But it keeps runing out of memory still.

Does anyone know what I need to do?

... after looking into it some more it now seems to me like it's a git process that causes the memory failure. initiated when I open a git managed project.
[image]

Excerp from log:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space   at
>   java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)     at
>   java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
>     at
>   java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
>     at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)   at
>   git4idea.history.GitHistoryUtils$2.onLineAvailable(GitHistoryUtils.java:579)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor129.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.dispatch(EventDispatcher.java:99)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher.access$200(EventDispatcher.java:35)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.EventDispatcher$2.invoke(EventDispatcher.java:79)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy123.onLineAvailable(Unknown Source)  at
>   git4idea.commands.GitLineHandler.notifyLine(GitLineHandler.java:144)
>     at
>   git4idea.commands.GitLineHandler.notifyLines(GitLineHandler.java:106)
>     at
>   git4idea.commands.GitLineHandler.onTextAvailable(GitLineHandler.java:74)
>     at
>   git4idea.commands.GitTextHandler$1.onTextAvailable(GitTextHandler.java:90)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor72.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$4.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:226)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.onTextAvailable(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTextAvailable(ProcessHandler.java:200)
>     at
>   com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler$SimpleOutputReader.onTextAvailable(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:290)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.io.BaseOutputReader.sendText(BaseOutputReader.java:202)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.io.BaseOutputReader.processInput(BaseOutputReader.java:186)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.io.BaseOutputReader.readAvailableBlocking(BaseOutputReader.java:140)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.io.BaseDataReader.readAvailable(BaseDataReader.java:82)
>     at com.intellij.util.io.BaseDataReader.doRun(BaseDataReader.java:160)
>     at com.intellij.util.io.BaseDataReader$1.run(BaseDataReader.java:61)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   2017-01-04 10:16:01,967 [ 393766]  ERROR -
>   .intellij.util.EventDispatcher - IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.2  Build
>   IU-163.10154.41  2017-01-04 10:16:01,967 [ 393766]  ERROR - .intellij.util.EventDispatcher - JDK: 1.8.0_112-release  2017-01-04
>   10:16:01,967 [ 393766]  ERROR - .intellij.util.EventDispatcher - VM:
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM  2017-01-04 10:16:01,967 [ 393766]  ERROR -
>   .intellij.util.EventDispatcher - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o  2017-01-04
>   10:16:01,967 [ 393766]  ERROR - .intellij.util.EventDispatcher - OS:
>   Mac OS X  2017-01-04 10:16:01,971 [ 393770]  ERROR -
>   .intellij.util.EventDispatcher - Last Action: EditCustomVmOptions 
>   2017-01-04 10:16:03,231 [ 395030]  ERROR -
>   .intellij.util.EventDispatcher - Java heap space

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the solution:
Add this to custom properties (via the help menu; edit custom properties)

```
vcs.log.index.git=off
```

That way Idea doesnt attempt to index your entire repo and

Comment: This didnt work with IntelliJ 2016.3.2... real pain..the memory dump issue.

Comment: If this had solve your issue considered marked as accepted :)

Comment: worked -  v2019.3