# Tagging large files with Stanford's Part-Of-Speech Tagger

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nlp, pos-tagger

I am currently using Java and the IntelliJ IDE to run Stanford's POS tagger. I have set it up using this tutorial:
(http://new.galalaly.me/index.php/2011/05/tagging-text-with-stanford-pos-tagger-in-java-applications/). It is running correctly, however, it only outputs roughly two paragraphs worth of text even when I give it much more content than that (the file I have has a size of 774 KB worth of text).

At the bottom of the tutorial it states this for memory problems:

> It turns out that the problem is that eclipse allocates on 256MB of
>   memory by default. RightClick on the Project->Run as->Run
>   Configurations->Go to the arguments tab-> under VM arguments type
>   -Xmx2048m This will set the allocated memory to 2GB and all the tagger files should run now.

I have configured IntelliJ to use 4GB of memory per this answer: [How to increase IDE memory limit in IntelliJ IDEA on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578062/how-to-increase-ide-memory-limit-in-intellij-idea-on-mac)

Yet, it did not change the amount of outputted text in the slightest.

What else could be causing this to happen?

(link to original site of the POS tagger: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml)

EDIT:

I have pasted my Main class below. And TaggedWord is a class that helps me parse and organize the relevant pieces of data retrieved from the tagger.

```
package com.company;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File infile = new File("C:\\Users\\TEST\\Desktop\\input.txt");
        File outfile = new File("C:\\Users\\TEST\\Desktop\\output.txt");
        MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("tagger/english-left3words-distsim.tagger");
        FileWriter fw;
        BufferedWriter bw;
        List<TaggedWord> taggedWords;

        try {
            //read in entire text file to String
            String fileContents = new Scanner(infile).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

            //erase contents of outfile from previous run
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outfile);
            pw.close();

            //tag file contents with parts of speech
            String fileContentsTagged = tagger.tagString(fileContents);

            taggedWords = processTaggedWords(fileContentsTagged);

            fw = new FileWriter(outfile, true); //true = append
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            String uasiContent = "";
            boolean firstWord = true;
            for (TaggedWord tw : taggedWords) {
                String englishWord = tw.getEng_word();
                String uasiWord = translate(englishWord);
                if (!tw.isPunctuation()) {
                    uasiContent += uasiWord + " ";
                }
                else {
                    //remove last space
                    uasiContent = uasiContent.substring(0, uasiContent.length() - 1);
                    uasiContent += uasiWord + " ";
                }
            }
            bw.write(uasiContent);
            bw.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("Error writing to file.");
        }
    }  //end main
```

EDIT2:

I have now modified the line where I am reading in the file to a string using the while-loop, but it still gives me the same results:

```
        //read in entire text file to String
        String fileContents = "";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(infile).useDelimiter("\\Z");
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            fileContents += sc.next();
        }
```

Comment: Not enough memory would give you an out of memory error rather than partial content - can you post relevant sections of your code where you are feeding the text and also where you are handling the output

Comment: I have now added my Main class above

Comment: You need to iterate through the scanner results - see answer below - let me know if you run into any issues

Comment: Hello Ahmed, I did as you suggested but it still reads in only a small amount. Could it be I'm using the wrong delimiter?

Comment: How are you trying to break the file? Newline/return? Periods? I am not familiar with \\Z delimiter. Another option is to use reader instead of scanner see SO question 16104616

Comment: The file is a book I got from Project Gutenburg. I copied file as-is from the site:
https://www.gutenberg.org/files/98/98-0.txt

It always read in up to "Chapter V      The Wine-shop"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166607/discussion-between-ahmed-s-and-nhershy).

Answer (score 1):

Your Scanner is only get called once where it reads the beginning of the input file. To continue, you need to declare Scanner stand-alone and then iterate using a while loop on hasNext() method. See document and [example here](http://javatutorialhq.com/java/util/scanner-class-tutorial/hasnext-method-example/) on declaring and iterating through scanner.